# Artemis master node not starting after failover to slave

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have an Artemis 2.11.0 HA pair configured using shared storage over NFS (but I don't know the mount options). Here's the master's `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>\\test\data\paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>\\test\data\bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>\\test\data\journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>\\test\data\large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <journal-buffer-timeout>752000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>false</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>

      
      <page-sync-timeout>1028000</page-sync-timeout>

      <global-max-size>4096Mb</global-max-size>
     
      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <master>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
            </master>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors> 
         <connector name="netty">tcp://ip-address:61617</connector>
      </connectors>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="teamsMQ-broadcast-group">
            <local-bind-address>ip-address</local-bind-address>
            <local-bind-port>9877</local-bind-port>
            <group-address>224.0.0.1</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>
 
      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="teamsMQ-discovery-group">
            <local-bind-address>ip-address</local-bind-address>
            <group-address>224.0.0.1</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty">tcp://ip-address:61617</acceptor>

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

And the slave's:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>\\test\data\paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>\\test\data\bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>\\test\data\journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>\\test\data\large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <journal-buffer-timeout>688000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>false</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      
      <page-sync-timeout>1028000</page-sync-timeout>

      <global-max-size>4096Mb</global-max-size>
      
      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
            <slave>
               <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
               <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
            </slave>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors> 
         <connector name="netty">tcp://ip-address:61617</connector>
      </connectors>

      <broadcast-groups>
         <broadcast-group name="teamsMQ-broadcast-group">
            <local-bind-address>ip-address</local-bind-address>
            <local-bind-port>9877</local-bind-port>
            <group-address>224.0.0.1</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
            <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
        </broadcast-group>
      </broadcast-groups>
 
      <discovery-groups>
         <discovery-group name="teamsMQ-discovery-group">
            <local-bind-address>ip-address</local-bind-address>
            <group-address>224.0.0.1</group-address>
            <group-port>9876</group-port>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
         </discovery-group>
      </discovery-groups>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty">tcp://ip-address:61617</acceptor>

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

The master node goes down for an unknown reason. The below log gets printed continuously:

```
AMQ222154: Error checking DLQ: ActiveMQShutdownException[errorType=SHUTDOWN_ERROR message=Journal must be in state=LOADED, was [STOPPED]]
```

```
2021-01-15 23:02:05,414 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222154: Error checking DLQ: ActiveMQShutdownException[errorType=SHUTDOWN_ERROR message=Journal must be in state=LOADED, was [STOPPED]] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.checkJournalIsLoaded(JournalImpl.java:1087) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendUpdateRecord(JournalImpl.java:886) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.Journal.appendUpdateRecord(Journal.java:98) [artemis-journal-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.updateDeliveryCount(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:756) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl.checkRedelivery(QueueImpl.java:3052) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.RefsOperation.rollbackRedelivery(RefsOperation.java:166) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.RefsOperation.afterRollback(RefsOperation.java:113) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl.afterRollback(TransactionImpl.java:589) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl.access$200(TransactionImpl.java:40) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.transaction.impl.TransactionImpl$4.done(TransactionImpl.java:442) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.OperationContextImpl$1.run(OperationContextImpl.java:244) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_275] 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_275] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
```

The Slave comes up as expected, but throws an NPE:

```
2021-01-15 23:02:27,529 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221010: Backup Server is now live
2021-01-15 23:02:27,545 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedStoreBackupActivation$FailbackChecker.<init>(SharedStoreBackupActivation.java:193) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedStoreBackupActivation.startFailbackChecker(SharedStoreBackupActivation.java:185) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.SharedStoreBackupActivation.run(SharedStoreBackupActivation.java:118) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0] 
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$ActivationThread.run(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:3863) [artemis-server-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
```

The master attempts to start, but it doesn't progress beyond `AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock`. The logs are stuck at this point even after multiple restarts.

```
2021-01-15 23:03:56,238 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
2021-01-15 23:03:56,300 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2021-01-15 23:03:56,581 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2021-01-15 23:03:56,644 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222035: Directory \\test\data\paging\cd776bae-1a55-11eb-985d-0050569136c8 did not have an identification file address.txt
2021-01-15 23:03:56,644 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222035: Directory \\test\data\paging\a84f1e4f-1f1a-11eb-a37f-0050569136c8 did not have an identification file address.txt
2021-01-15 23:03:56,644 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222035: Directory \\test\data\paging\a87edff5-1f1a-11eb-a37f-0050569136c8 did not have an identification file address.txt
2021-01-15 23:03:56,988 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
```

Can you please advise on the issue here and the steps to recover?

Does the NPE in the slave start-up have any effects on the queue/functioning?

Do I need to stop the Slave manually to get the master to start successfully?

Comment: Also, I would expect to see additional details about the broker shutdown *before* the `SHUTDOWN_ERROR` messages. Can you provide the full log file?

Comment: Yes, It is NFS Shared store, The issue is in one of our customer's instance and I don't have the details of mount options.

Answer (score 0):

If the master broker encounters any "critical IO" problems it will automatically shut itself down. When it shuts itself down it will relinquish the lock it has on the shared journal. When the shared lock is relinquished the slave will automatically activate. When the master is restarted it will attempt to acquire the lock on the shared journal but it won't be able to since the slave has it.

The slave failed to set up the `FailbackChecker` thread due to a `NullPointerException` because there is no `<cluster-connection>` configured in either `broker.xml`. This is an *invalid* configuration. You *must* configure a `<cluster-connection>`, e.g.:

```xml
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
            <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="teamsMQ-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
```

Since the `FailbackChecker` thread isn't running the slave will not know that the master has restarted and initiated a fail-back. Therefore, you will need to stop the slave so it can relinquish its lock on the shared journal. At this point the master broker will start. Keep in mind that any clients connected to the slave will be disconnected and will have to reconnect to the master.

Comment: I have added the broker XML here:
https://gist.github.com/suman-moorthy/3a2c4457a7139be9b93c88167a4364f4

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comments. I also updated your question with the new configuration details you've provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try this configuration and let you know

Comment: Tried with the latest recommended broker.xml configuration where we use JGroups.

1. Start master server, It obtains live lock.
2. Start slave server, it obtains backup lock.
At this moment console for both servers is accessible.
3. Stop master server, Slave server obtains the live lock.
4. Start the master server.
Observed lot of timeout errors and the master server console is not accessible.
5. Stopped slave server, master server obtained the live lock.
Observed that the master server console is accessible now.

Comment: Logs and broker xml files are here
https://gist.github.com/suman-moorthy/a15ab87c5c656abff48f3093c474a2bc

Comment: Why are you using JGroups? ActiveMQ Artemis has native support for both static (i.e. TCP) and dynamic (i.e. UDP multicast) clustering. JGroup support was added for cloud-based use cases were UDP multicast doesn't work and static configuration is impractical. Also, is `test-jgroups-file_ping.xml` on a shared drive where both brokers can read it and write to it?